# how to use explode function

Tags: python, csv, explode

I am working on dataset named "data" and what to use explode function but facing error in this code. **Error**:-***'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'*** and showing attribute error

```
artists_exploded = data[['artists_upd','id']].explode('artists_upd')
```

Comment: inplace of explode you can use this: `np.hstack(df['artists_upd'].str.split('; '))`

Comment: Make sure you are using *pandas>=0.25* for using explode function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you are trying to explode data on 2 columns (artists & ID), but this is how you do it for just artists_upd. Perhaps you want to use a different value for str.split(), depending on your data.

```
artists_exploded = data.assign(artists_upd = data.artists_upd.str.split(",")).explode("artists_upd")
```